# Delete all rows in a table with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a simple chat application that posts people's messages, and that gives the user an option to "reset" the chat which will delete all messages from the database so the user can start over. The messages post okay, but the reset button just sends an empty post (instead of deleting all current posts). I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong:

```
if ( isset($_POST['reset']) ) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {$p}sample_chat WHERE chat = :CHA";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':CHA' => $_POST['message']));
    header( 'Location: '.sessionize('index.php') ) ;
    return;
}
```

Per a comment below, I've updated my client side code to be:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo($CFG->staticroot); ?>/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<body>

<form id="chats" method="post">
<input type="text" size="60" name="message" />
<input type="submit" value="Chat"/>
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
<a style="color:grey" href="chatlist.php" target="_blank">Launch chatlist.php</a>
</form>
<p id="messages" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function htmlentities(str) {
   return $('<div/>').text(str).html();
}

function updateMsg() {
  window.console && console.log("Requesting JSON"); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo(sessionize('chatlist.php')); ?>',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      window.console && console.log("JSON Received"); 
      window.console && console.log(data);
      $("#chatcontent").empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        entry = data[i];
        $("#chatcontent").append("<p>"+entry[0] +
                "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+entry[1]+"</p>\n");
            window.console && console.log("entry " + entry[0]);
          }
          setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
        }
      });
    }
    window.console && console.log("Startup complete"); 
    updateMsg();

    </script>
    </p>
    </body>
```

The code in its entirety, in case I've missed something/context is helpful:

```
<?php
require_once "../../config.php";
require_once $CFG->dirroot."/pdo.php";
require_once $CFG->dirroot."/lib/lms_lib.php";

// This is a very minimal index.php - just enough to launch
// chatlist.php with the PHPSESSIONID parameter
session_start();

// Retrieve the launch data if present
$LTI = requireData(array('user_id', 'result_id', 'role','link_id'));
$instructor = isset($LTI['role']) && $LTI['role'] == 1 ;
$p = $CFG->dbprefix;

if ( isset($_POST['message']) ) {             
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$p}sample_chat 
    (link_id, user_id, chat, created_at) 
    VALUES (:LI, :UID, :CHA, NOW() ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE chat = :CHA, created_at = NOW()";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':LI' => $LTI['link_id'],
        ':UID' => $LTI['user_id'],
        ':CHA' => $_POST['message']));
    $messages = array();
    header( 'Location: '.sessionize('index.php') ) ;
    return;
}

if ( isset($_POST['reset']) ) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {$p}sample_chat WHERE chat = :CHA";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':CHA' => $_POST['message']));
    header( 'Location: '.sessionize('index.php') ) ;
    return;
}

?>

<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo($CFG->staticroot); ?>/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<body>

<form id="chats" method="post">
<input type="text" size="60" name="message" />
<input type="submit" value="Chat"/>
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
<a style="color:grey" href="chatlist.php" target="_blank">Launch chatlist.php</a>
</form>
<p id="messages" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function htmlentities(str) {
   return $('<div/>').text(str).html();
}

function updateMsg() {
  window.console && console.log("Requesting JSON"); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo(sessionize('chatlist.php')); ?>',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      window.console && console.log("JSON Received"); 
      window.console && console.log(data);
      $("#chatcontent").empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        entry = data[i];
        $("#chatcontent").append("<p>"+entry[0] +
            "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+entry[1]+"</p>\n");
        window.console && console.log("entry " + entry[0]);
      }
      setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
    }
  });
}
window.console && console.log("Startup complete"); 
updateMsg();

</script>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: if $_POST is empty, then you should be showing your client-side html/form code.

Comment: That information has been added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major issue:

```
 $.getJSON('<?php echo(sessionize('chatlist.php')); ?>', function(data){
   ^^^--- using http GET

if ( isset($_POST['reset']) ) {
             ^^^^---expecting HTTP POST
```

`.getJSON()` is for **GET** requests only. If you want to use a POST, you'll have to use $.ajax() instead.

Comment: I've updated it to ajax, but now my messages are not being displayed and the reset button still does not clear old messages.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a GET request using ajax. Make a POST request. Add **Type**. For Example

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggests best thing you can do is: Use PHP REQUEST variable. Using it use can accept either post or get requests. i.e. For example:

`if ( isset($_REQUEST['reset']) ) {
          /***Code to delete chat **/
}`